# error de compilación en java

Tags: java

Al compilar en cmd mi maven project de java me tira este error(package does not exits import...). Tengo una interface ILevel, IBrick y una clase printer y he importado lo que necesito, sin embargo no se a que se deberá este error. Busque en la red sobre este error y me parece que no es ni tan conocido ni desconocido, espero que alguien me pueda ayudar.

[image: En este imagen intento compilar el metodo ILevel y no lo puedo hacer.]

Comment: Jose, dentro de que estructura de folders se encuentra la clase IBrick ??? Si es posible agrega tu archivo Maven.

Answer (score 0):

Jose, creo que es algo común este problema,

> Error package com.cc3002.breakout.logic.IBrick does not exist

En la linea 23 de la clase `ILevel.java` indica que no existe la clase `IBrick`:

```
public List<IBrick> getBricks();
```

Eso quiere decir que en esta clase el import para accesar a la clase `IBrick` es incorrecto.

Asegura agregar el import correcto.

Comment: Gracias Jorgesys!!. Era una tarea de la u y después no preste más atención a este hilo.  Se valora la intención de todas maneras !!